# How to set common rule for all <p> elements to fit into page with various font sizes?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I using a rtf-html converter which converts rtf document into html. In the html container I am facing hard time to fit converted rtf document into a container for different font-sizes. Here are some fiddles which show how contents are in the container when I set the conveted RTF contents in to HTML.

font size 6pt : https://jsfiddle.net/r4ad9yg7/

font size 7pt : https://jsfiddle.net/osg91jb5/

font size 8pt : https://jsfiddle.net/tazpLy19/1/

font size 9pt : https://jsfiddle.net/o2wtx08z/

font size 10pt : https://jsfiddle.net/rpu62gvk/

font size 11pt : https://jsfiddle.net/2bonhf57/

I need a common css rules  for all the font sizes of `<p>` which will fit into container (`<body>`) by adjusting margin, padding or lineHeight of `<p>` elements.

[image: white space]

I need to remove above white space by increasing margin or padding or... of the `<p>` elements. CANNOT ADD ANY ADDITIONAL `<P>` ELEMENTS, the rtf data are match exactly in the pages

Answer (score 0):

Check New Css in Body tag.

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 6.98in;
  height: 11.15in;
  
}
.top{
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
@page {
  size: 6.98in 11.15in
}

p {
  line-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10pt;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="generator" content="LibreOffice 6.0.7.3 (Linux)" />
    <meta name="created" content="00:00:00" />
    <meta name="changed" content="00:00:00" />
  </head>

  <body lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
  <div class="top">
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">0</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">1</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">2</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">3</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">4</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">5</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">6</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">7</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">8</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">9</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">10</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">11</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">12</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">13</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">14</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">15</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">16</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">17</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">18</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">19</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">20</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">21</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">22</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">23</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">24</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">25</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">26</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">27</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">28</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">29</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">30</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">31</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">32</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">33</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">34</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">35</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">36</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">37</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">38</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">39</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">40</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">41</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">42</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">43</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">44</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">45</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">46</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">47</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">48</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">49</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">50</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">51</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">52</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">53</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">54</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">55</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">56</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">57</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">58</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">59</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">60</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">61</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">62</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">63</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">64</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">65</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">66</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">67</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; line-height: 100%">
      <font color="#000000">
        <font face="Arial, serif">
          <font size="2" style="font-size: 10pt">68</font>
        </font>
      </font>
    </p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: the css styling must be applied to <p> element not <body>.

Comment: Can we add new <div> tag ? after body tag ?